# it were best (to) & I were best (to)

Tags: grammar

Shakespeare's plays are replete with both these constructions.

Is *were* in these constructions equivalent to the modern *would*?

Answer (score 2):

The *were* in these words is what in most languages is called the subjunctive - *conjunctivul* in Romanian.

In today's speech, one would simply say "it was best to" and "I was best to".

The subjunctive has almost fully disappeared from English, but there are vestiges: "if I were", "Long live the King", etc.

The function of the now-obsolete subjunctive is not that different from how you use it in Romanian - or any other Latin language.

Comment: Not really, I can say ce faci and multumesc ;-) I did want to learn it back in the day, but never got to it.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! :-) Did my answer help?

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I was just rephrasing your two examples, I've corrected it now - the first one was meant to be "it was best to"

Comment: That'll be lovely, I'll look it up but can't promise to come back right away - I can be quite bad with emails. But would love to, cheers.

Comment: I disagree; in today's speech, one would say ***it would be best to*** or ***I would do best to.*** The subjunctive was replaced by the use of auxiliary verbs, not by the indicative (except in the construction *"if it were"*, which is being replaced by *"if it was"*).